# How can I get the searched value from this FireBase DataSnapshot

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I get the

> "Dancing in the dark"

from this snapshot if the snapshot does not exist:? I figure it must be saved in the snapshot somewhere. Please read inline code comments..

```
  private void addListenerForSingleValueEvent(String streetAddress, StringBuilder targetAddress){

        DatabaseReference firebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        firebase.child("catalog/trax").orderByChild("namn").equalTo("Dancing in the dark")
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                 // do sowm work on existing data
                } else {
                 // How can I get the "Dancing in the dark" from the snapshot?
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(Application.getInstance(), databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result. By listening to a `value` event you get all matching results in one snapshot, so you have to iterate over the children.

```
    DatabaseReference firebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    firebase.child("catalog/trax").orderByChild("namn").equalTo("Dancing in the dark")
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot item: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                // In this loop item is the snapshot of a single item.
                // This means we can get the namm of the item
                System.out.println(item.child("namm").getValue(String.class));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(Application.getInstance(), databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Lets say that `!snapshot.exists()` , there is nothing in the `snapshot`, can I still from the `snapshot` extract what I was searching for, the question:, `("catalog/trax").orderByChild("namn").equalTo("Dancing in the dark")` Or maybe I can save that as a field in the class sure that works but anyway